# Check Content Type in Page PreProcess Hook

Tags: 8, theming

I'm attempting to get the content type in my page preprocess function...but apparently I'm missing something.  What am I doing wrong here?  I'm attempting to get the $node variables first - then test from there.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
   $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
   switch ($node->getType()) {
       case "client":
           $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'clientpage';
       break;
        case "something_else":
           // ...
       break;
   }    
 }
```

Comment: any error messages?

Comment: Not every URL/page is a node. Before doing `$node->getType()` you should check for the correct object `if ($node instanceof NodeInterface) ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of looking at the route parameter, you can also do:

`$node = $variables['node'];`

Here is some example code that I have that is working from `preprocess_page`:

```
    $node = $variables['node'];

    if ($node instanceof NodeInterface) {
      $type = $node->getType();

      if ($type == 'listing_page' && trim($node->getTitle()) == 'News') {
        $variables['is_news_page'] = TRUE;
      }
    }
```

Don't forget your `use ...` statement if you check node is `NodeInterface`.

So this is definitely doable - if you are getting any error messages please post them and double check your content type machine names.